# CREATE INDEX MySQL 5.6.13 On Production Database

Tags: mysql, indexing, locking

I am running MySQL 5.6.13 and I would like to run a `CREATE INDEX ... BTREE` statement on my production database.

The table is InnoDB and has ~ 4 million rows, and I would like very much not to lock it.

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html), it appears as if this statement **will not completely lock my table** and return quickly.  But, I wanted a second opinion before I made this change.

Would it be safe to create this index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, InnoDB in MySQL 5.6 will perform a *read lock* while creating the index, so you can still have other concurrent clients SELECT from the table, but not do insert/update/delete on that table while the index is being created.

You can optionally allow the index creation to be completely online and not even do the read lock:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX a (a), LOCK=NONE;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html for more details about online DDL statements in MySQL.

Also see this blog posted today from a MySQL Community Manager: [Top 10 advances to availability since MySQL 5.5](http://www.tocker.ca/2013/10/22/top-10-advances-to-availability-since-mysql-5-5.html)

PS: It's not necessary to specify BTREE for the index type. InnoDB supports only BTREE indexes, so it ignores that option.

Comment: I added the `BTREE` part that just to be clear it wasn't a fulltext index, which seems to lock everything.

Are there any consequences by not having it lock?

Comment: The online index creation doesn't work for PRIMARY or UNIQUE keys, but as far as I know, there are no issues. On the other hand, virtually every other feature new in MySQL 5.6 has had some unforeseen issues, so I'd encourage you to test carefully and research bugs.mysql.com.